# Match html tags in c# regex matcher

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match the contens in between the </strong> ....<strong> in the following

> "\n<strong>Address:</strong> <br>\nHennessy Park Hotel, 65, Ebene Cybercity, Ebene \n<br>\<strong>Phone:</strong> (230) 403 7200<br>\n\n<strong>Fax:</strong> (230) 403 7201<br>\n<strong>Contact:</strong> <a href="/contact.html">Send E-mail</a><br>\n\n<p>\n"

Is there a way to do that. Currently i am using

```
Match result = Regex.Match(box.InnerHtml, @"<\/strong>(.*?)<strong>", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
```

But I am not getting the contents that i wanted.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/770270

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will allow you to select the contents including the *strong* tags across multiple lines.

```
<strong>(.|\n)*?<\/strong>
```

This will allow you to select the content between the *strong* tags:

```
<strong>([\s\S]*?)<\/strong>
```

This will allow you to select the content between the ***end*** strong tag and the ***start*** strong tag:

```
<\/strong>([\s\S]*?)<strong>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: This would group every single character individually and you won't easily be able to access the results. For this solution to work, you'd need to use `([\s\S]*?)` instead of what you currently have between the strong tags.

Comment: Pluto, You are absolutely correct. I will update my post.

Answer (score 1):

To do it with C#, you would change your call to add `RegexOptions.Singleline`. Since the [`RegexOptions` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has the `[FlagsAttribute]`, you can combine multiple flags with the bitwise-or operator (`|`).

Your new call would look like this (scroll to the end):

```
Match result = Regex.Match(box.InnerHtml, @"<\/strong>(.*?)<strong>", RegexOptions.ECMAScript | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

See this article for a full description of using the flags: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I misunderstood your question on my last answer. I believe the regex you're looking for is `<\/strong>(.*?).*<strong>` This will return a match of `</strong> <br>\nHennessy Park Hotel, 65, Ebene Cybercity, Ebene \n<br>\<strong>Phone:</strong> (230) 403 7200<br>\n\n<strong>Fax:</strong> (230) 403 7201<br>\n<strong>`

Comment: I don't think he wants to match "Address:", "Phone:", etc. He wants to match actual data values.

Comment: I believe you're right @Pluto. I've edited the answer.